# Flutter GradleException error after changing minSdkVersion

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

so I just changed some settings in my flutter build.gradle project and I changed the minSdkVersion from 16 to 19 since this was required to use a widget (WebView to be exact). However, since changing this, the error shown below occurs

[image: GradleExecption Error]

Its weird since I can still run the program just fine and I can even comment and hide the code and it will run fine, buts its just really annoying having red lines in my project...

and yes flutter.sdk is already defined in my local.properties file

[image]

So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem earlier and solved this by changing 'GradleException' to 'FileNotFoundException.'

It worked for me, so hopefully it helps, good luck!

PS. I could not find out technically why this worked!

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local
```